# Roblox packet loss?

Tags: technical-issues, roblox

Since a couple months ago my roblox ping has been spiking. My ping was normal since the past couple years until now. I tried to get a better internet plan, use ethernet, tried different PCs and I'm still having pink spikes. I don't know whats the cause of the problem. It's like it randomly appeared to mess with me.
When I'm on a pserver my ping is normal, but as soon as someone else joins and I start pvping them (or an NPC) the ping starts spiking from 80 to 500-600 then back to 80 after like 3 seconds. I already tried contacting Roblox support and they told me it could be because of my ISP or my ports not being open? I don't know anymore I just need some assistance since I can't play anything on Roblox.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are not running any VPNs or any extensions that may slow down your internet. The weirdest part to me is that this happens with NPC too. I would make sure that your PC is not maxed out by opening the task manager and checking that.

It sounds like a Wi-Fi issue to me. If you are running 80 ping on average, it is not great Wi-Fi. If you don't think this is it, answer the following questions:

- Does this happen on all Roblox games? If no, then it is most likely a game issue that everyone suffers.
- Does this happen on other games outside of Roblox? If the answer is no, delete Roblox and redownload.

Answer (score -2):

try making a new windows account. I had the same issue and it worked for me

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Exchange! We appreciate your answer, but there are a few issues:
1) How do you know the asker is using Windows?
2) Why does this fix it? This shouldn’t fix it, and if you claim it does you should provide an explanation or at the very least a little bit of explanation and a source as I am sure many now and many in the future will be confused by this answer.